# React Data Flow Into a Separate Component File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

**Lets say that I have this main js file in react:**

```
<code>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Data from './components/data';
import './App.css';

var todos = [
  {
    todoTitle: "My first todo",
    todoResponsible: "Kevin",
    todoDescription: "My first todo description",
    todoPriority: "low"
  },
  {
    todoTitle: "My second todo",
    todoResponsible: "Sam",
    todoDescription: "My second todo description",
    todoPriority: "medium"
  },
  {
    todoTitle: "My third todo",
    todoResponsible: "Hobbs",
    todoDescription: "My Third todo description",
    todoPriority: "high"
  }
]

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos
    };
  }

  `render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Data />
      </div>`
    );
  }
}

export default App;
</code>
```

---

**If I want to pass the data that is in var todos to this component in a separate file:**

```
<code>
`import React, { Component } from 'react';

`class Data extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
      </ul>`
    );
  }
}

export default Data;`
</code>
```

**How would I go about in doing so? I tried to look online for resources but it only showed passing data through a single component.
Thank you in advance and please help if you could~**

Answer (score 1):

You can pass todos data as a props to Data component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos
    };
  }

  `render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Data todos={this.state.todos} />
      </div>`
    );
  }
}
```

In Data component you have easy acces to them by `this.props.todos` :

```
class Data extends Component {
  render(){
    console.log(this.props.todos);
    return(
      <ul>
        <li>
        </li>
      </ul>`
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `todos` to your `Data` component using `<Data todos={this.state.todos} />` from your `App` component. And then you can use `todos` from your `Data` component using something like:

```js
class Data extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
      {
        this.props.todos.map(todo => <li>{todo.todoTitle}</li>)
      }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```